# how to restart script if it stops working but still shows as running under supervisor

Tags: python, python-2.7, supervisord

I have a python script running under supervisor.

I chose supervisor cause it will auto start the script when machine boots up and when the script supposedly "dies"

What it does is it will keep writing to a log file `running.log` every 3-6 seconds after performing some actions.

If there are exceptions, it will write the exception to a separate logfile.

The script stopped writing to `running.log` after 5 hours despite no exceptions during that time.

It still shows as running under supervisor and there are no exceptions during the time it supposedly stopped writing to the `running.log`.

Yet it stopped writing to the `running.log` script despite successfully doing so for 5 hrs.

I then manually restarted the service again under supervisor.

What are my options?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind: there is some bug in the script. You should fix that, ensuring that the script dies... or another option would be to throw some "watchdog" mechanism in it (although I would not recommend that course of action).

Comment: I am unsure how to replicate this bug as I can go hours before I detect this stop. could I write a script that basically checks the size of the `running.log` every 30 seconds and if it fails to change, then the script tells supervisor to restart the service?

Comment: That would be a watchdog mechanism. Note that the bug remains, I would advise (first) to try to debug it --attaching a debugger to the running process once failed, for instance.

Comment: `attaching a debugger to the running process once failed, for instance` i have two issues: 1. my python script is running live on production server, 2. i have no idea how to attach a debugger to a running python process

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two options:

## 1. Find the bug

The script is unresponsive but not dead. That means that is has deadlocked itself, or went into an infinite loop, or locked in some I/O procedure or whatever.

I would say that finding the bug and removing it is a great course of action! You can look into the code and feel where that can happen, add some log verbosity or similar. Or you can debug it. There are mechanisms to attach a debugger to a running Python script:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb

You will need permissions to do that. If it is a production code, then that is bad news... but having a undetected undefined bug in a production machine does not feel right. So maybe you could set up some stage machine and debug the script there? This way you could find where is the problem.

## 2. Add some watchdog mechanism

You could add some process to watch the script. In fact, the script itself can `multiprocess` it into something to watch the log file modification time. Skeleton (untested):

```
def watch(watch_path):
    last_modified = <get modification time of watch_path>
    while True:
        <sleep>
        if <check modification times>:
            <kill> os.getppid()  # kill parent process
        else:
            last_modified = <get modification time>

...

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=watch, args=(log_output_path,))
```